# Adding two .NET SqlDecimals increases precision?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

in .NET, when I add two SqlDecimals, like so:

```
SqlDecimal s1 = new SqlDecimal(1);
SqlDecimal s2 = new SqlDecimal(1);
SqlDecimal s3 = s1 + s2;
```

then s3 has precision 2, whereas both s1 and s2 have precision 1.

This seems odd, especially as the documentation states that the return value of the addition operator is "A new SqlDecimal structure whose Value property contains the sum." I.e. according to the documentation, addition should not change the precision.

Am I missing something here? Is this intended behaviour?

Cheers,

Tilman

Comment: Often time for instance in the case of adding two float values the result is say a double to take into account overflow.  So what seems odd is not actually odd, it makes a great deal of sense, given the right context.

Comment: Thanks, after re-reading the definition of 'precision' it actually made a lot more sense... Then again, shouldn't the addition operation take the actual value into account and only adjust the precision if necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) explains the behavior for the SQL types, and I assume the .NET Sql data types reflect that in their behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I find this behavior normal.

`Precision` is defined as *the maximum number of digits used to represent the* `Value` *property*.

The sum of two `SqlDecimal` numbers who's `Precision` is equal to `1` is a number contained in [-10,10]. In which case the maximum `Precision` required is `2`.